# How to fix woodpecker damage on wood siding?

Tags: wood, siding

A woodpecker has been busy while we were overseas, and has created the damage you can see

[image]

Assuming I figure out why he has been doing this (I believe is nesting reasons), my question is how can I fix the wood damage? Specifically:

1. How do I remove the top 2x4, and how do I place the new one place back in? Is that placed using glue?
2. How do I remove the siding so that I don't have to remove the whole siding, but just the part that is damaged? As in, how do I cut it safely?

Comment: Are you sure that's woodpecker damage?  To me, that looks more like rodents chewing, especially with how wide the chewing area is.  Usually in my experience that woodpeckers do more round holes if for nesting purposes.

Comment: Yep, my father in law has seen it and heard pecking almost every morning :(. I hope I haven't had rats join the party too! I will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut or patch

If you cut it you will have problems reinstalling the 2 x 4 and still have to insert a pice of siding somehow.

I would recommend leaving everything as is and patch it with piece of siding.

To do that cut a pice of siding to the length.

Attaching it will also cover the unsightly gap on the left.

If you are crafty you can cut the arch in the replacement siding (using a Jig saw) to close up the hole in the 2x4 followed by some wood filler.

To get the guide for cutting the arch, use a pice of carton and mark it with the contour of the wood picker job.

Comment: Thanks - How would you attach the siding patch to the existing siding / 2x4? Using nails?

Comment: Yes, just nails

Comment: its usually easier to cut out all the damage by a rectangle box around the problem, then your patch is easier to cut and plane into a perfect fit.

Comment: Ruskes, but how would you put the nail from the new siding to the top 2x4?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine nails hidden under paint are holding the 2x4 and siding.

The top pieces are the easiest to remove, since you just need to remove those two.

Wedge a small prybar or hammer under the top edge and pull gently. It should start to move.

Repeat along the length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A couple of questions:

- For the siding, do you suggest removing the whole slat? I'd rather just remove the part that is damaged, but I'm not sure how to cut it.
- For the 2x4, how do you attach it to the top part?

Comment: It would be easier to cut/fix if it was taken off.

Comment: Makes sense, crip. And the 2x4, how is that attached to the top part? Wouldn't I need to nail it from above?

Comment: Almost certainly 
 nailed from the side. This is a part that _will_  be replaced sooner or later; no reason to make that more difficult. And nailing from above wouldn't hold as well.

Comment: @Nobita   Depending on where the structural wood is behind it, could be nailed straight from the outside or at an angle into the top.